# listing generic relations in Django

Tags: django

I have a **generic relation** in a class called **Unsubscribe**. The relation at the moment links to a class called **Contact**.

I would like to **list all Unsubscribe Contacts** in  view. My question is, **where do I list from?** Contacts or Unsubscribed? i.e. Should I be writing a view from my contacts app or my unsubscribe app, which end should I come at it from?

Thanks

```
class Unsubscribe(models.Model):
    """

    Notes:
    See: http://www.screamingatmyscreen.com/2012/6/django-and-generic-relations/
    """
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, help_text="Represents the name of the model")
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(help_text="stores the object id")
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    reason = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    request_made = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                   help_text="Shows when object was created.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a generic relation, there would be other models apart from `Contact` which would be related to this model as well. So, `Unsubscribe` would be also associated with other models.

What you want to do is specific to `Contact`, so I guess it should go in the views.py of `contact` app.
Also, conventionally it depends on what is the url you will be serving it from. If your url is something like `/contacts/unsubscribed`, it should be in `contacts` app.

But if you want to keep track of unsubscribed model objects at one place it could go in `unsubscribe` app. eg: Say you want to show unsubscribed contacts at `/unsubscribed/contacts/` and want to show unsubscribed `foos` at `/unsubscribed/foos/`, then it should be in unsubscribe app.

So, depends a great deal on how your url structure should be and how you want to use it.